# adding data in table after logged in in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

Hello I new in codeigniter!... I made tow tables one for admin who can make log in , after logged he want to add data inside other table (building) , the other table has admin_id as foreign key. so when there many admins  and every one want to add data, how I can store admin_id with every data,,, what I should write inside model also if I have been stored the user_id in session (inside controller) as following:

```
if($this->form_validation->run()){
    $result = $this->validate_admins(); 
    if($result){
          $admin_ID = $this->adminship_model->get_adminID($this->input->post('email')); 
 $data = array(
         'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
         'password'=>md5($this->input->post('password')),
         'is_logged_in' => '1',
         'admin_id' => $admin_ID

       );
   $this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

this code in model, but not complete, the problem is here

```
function form_insert(){

 /* /  $query = $this->db->query('select admin_id from admin where email = ""'); */
   //echo $query; 

  $data = array(

   'owner_name'            => $this->input->post('owner_name'),
   'owner_telephone'       => $this->input->post('owner_telephone'),
   'owner_mobile'          => $this->input->post('owner_mobile'),
   'owner_email'          =>   $this->input->post('owner_email'),
   'building_name'         => $this->input->post('building_name'),
   'building_street'         => $this->input->post('building_street'),
   'building_city'         => $this->input->post('building_city'),
   'full_address'         => $this->input->post('full_address'),
   'no_of_floors'          => $this->input->post('no_of_floors'),
   'no_of_apartments'      => $this->input->post('no_of_apartments'),
   'building_description'  => $this->input->post('building_description')
   // I wanna   add photo.

      );

          $this->db->insert('building', $data);
          //$email_fk = $this->db->mysqli_insert_id(); 

       echo "dooooooooooooooooooooooooon!";

    }
```

This is my Database Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `building` (
  `building_ID` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `owner_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `owner_telephone` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `owner_mobile` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `owner_email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `building_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `building_street` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `no_of_apartments` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `no_of_floors` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `building_description` text NOT NULL,
  `building_imgs` longblob,
  `The_engineering_plan_img` longblob,
  `admin_id` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `building_city` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `full_address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`building_ID`),
  KEY `admin_id` (`admin_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

this is the error:
A Database Error Occurred

> Error Number: 1452
>
> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`managing buildings`.`building`, CONSTRAINT `building_ibfk_1` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`admin_id`) REFERENCES `admin` (`admin_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON
>   UPDATE CASCADE)

```
INSERT INTO `building` (
    `owner_name`,
    `owner_telephone`,
    `owner_mobile`,
    `owner_email`,
    `building_name`,
    `building_street`,
    `building_city`,
    `full_address`,
    `no_of_floors`,
    `no_of_apartments`,
    `building_description`
)
VALUES
    (
        'john joly',
        '0352354121',
        '0596854218',
        'john@outlook.com',
        'bluesky',
        'main street',
        'madrid',
        'main street- bluesky-bno25',
        '13',
        '26',
        '\r\nnice place'
    )
```

any help is appreciated :)

Comment: as the error says, you are required to remove the foreign key in admin_id, or you can make a primary key in reference and make it auto increamental and do not insert admin_id in INSERT INTO query

Comment: In admin table admin_id is the auto incremental primary key and in building table its foreign.. my question is how to store it in building table? with the entered data with Knowing there more than admin and every one has buildings. And after fill data he  want to view his buildings.

@Marmik Bhatt

Comment: then you have to remove FOREIGN KEY constraint from building table

Comment: how and why to remove? please explain more?

Comment: it is advisable to remove foriegn key constraints

Answer (score 0):

You need also set admin_ID when you insert into building table, because he is a foreign key and not null, you have to set value any way.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$this->db->query("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0");
```

above the insert query

Answer (score 0):

I stored the admin_id in side session then i take it from session. then it stored in building table.by adding it inside the array in model.